# Connecting to a MySQL database on Mac from a VMWare fusion Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, mariadb, mac-os-x, vmware

I have MariaDB (5.5.34-MariaDB) installed on a Mac (OS 10.8.5) I can connect to the database fine locally (127.0.0.1) on port 3306. But when I try to connect to the database from windows 7 64bit running in VMWare fusion I get an error message.

[image: Error message when connecting from windows]

I am using 32bit ODBC, as I believe that is what is required. I do have Little Snitch running on the mac side, but I have checked this and it is not blocking the connection. Windows side does have the firewall enabled, but I have added a rule to allow outgoing connections on port 3306. I have tried telnet from windows on port 3306 to the Mac and it also fails. Pinging the Mac from windows works fine.

Checking my.cnf, there does not seem to be anything that would block the connection. No bind-address = 127.0.0.1 in the file. I have added permissions for the user to connect from the IP using the GRANT SQL command. I am at a loss on how to get this working so any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out. I used home-brew to install MariaDB and as part of the setup it was using launchctl to start the server. The file ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist had --bind=127.0.0.1 in it.

Comment: Did you remove this entry (`<string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>`) from the plist?

Comment: Yes that is correct